# IntegrityError when using .save() on OneToOneField in Django

Tags: django

I have 2 models

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

class Authentication(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    token = models.CharField(max_length =50, null = True)
```

Here is the code I use for login in views.py

```
from user.models import User, Authentication
import uuid
from django.db.utils import IntegrityError

user = User.objects.get(pk = request.user.id)
token = uuid.uuid4().hex
try:
    Authentication.objects.create(user = user, token = token)
except IntegrityError:
    user.authentication.token = token
    user.authentication.save()
return JsonResponse({'token':token})
```

The problem I meet here is everytime a user login, I will generate a new token and save in the database. The error appears at the line

```
user.authentication.save()
```

The error is: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '30' for key 'user_id' ")
The 30 is the user_id existed in Authentication models when login in the second time ( the first time login is always succeed).
I solved this problem by using these codes:

```
except IntegrityError:
    au = Authentication.objects.get(user = user)
    au.token = token
    au.save()
```

But I dont know why i got this bug. I used to do the first approach many times but not got no bugs at all. Anyone has faced to this problem can show me the way to solve this? Thank you

Comment: Is that an Authentication model you have made yourself? if so... why? Django has built in authentication that handles: logins https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/

Comment: User and Authentication is 2 models I created not from django built-in auth system

Comment: are users allowed to login from multiple devices?

Comment: no. so that why i saved the token in database and send it with cookie then check the request to check authentication.

Comment: so, how will you deal with the case when a user logs from another device?

Comment: oh it's quite easy. when user login in 1 device, i will generate a new token and save it in Authentication model and set in cookie. Then if that user login another device, a new token will be generated and saved so the old token will be gone so the first device  cannot access because the token saved in cookie checked with the token saved in model has been wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to create a new token to a user who already have one, and since you've defined a `OneToOneField` it is not possible. I suggest you to try the `get_or_create()` instead of `create()` method.

Alternatively, you can modify the create method:

```
try:
    auth = Authentication.objects.create(user = request.user)
except Exception as e:
    #do something
return JsonResponse({'token': auth.token})
```

In models.py

```
from user.managers import MyManager

class Authentication(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    token = models.CharField(max_length =50, null = True)
    objects = MyManager()
```

Then create a file 'managers.py' and put this in it:

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, user):
        token = uuid.uuid4().hex
        if user.authentication:
            user.authentication.token = token
            user.authentication.save()
            return user.authentication
        else:
            auth = self.model(user=user, token=token)
            auth.save(using=self._db)
            return auth
```

Now if you use `Authentication.objects.create(user=request.user)` the `create` method in `MyManager` will be invoked. This also helps to separate token generation from views.py

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should have look at django builtin [auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/) system. For your approach

```
try:
    obj = Authentication.objects.get(user=user)
    obj.token = token
    obj.save()
except Authentication.DoesNotExist:
    Authentication.objects.create(user = user, token = token)
```